# I did findelement using Xpath, the next step i need to is findelement.text(); to get the text. how i can do that

Tags: selenium, c#

This is the xpath for the text I need to find-----

```
/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/font
```

->

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/font"));
```

Next I need to use `findelement.text();` and I need to store Xpath's text value in variable so I can use it for calculation. This Xpath's text is numeric which is actually a text, which I need to convert it in to integer.

So can you help me out , how to use `findelement.Text();` and how to convert text to integer?

Comment: can you please add the source of the location?  By the looks of it there may be a better mechanism of finding the element (id/CSS/XPath).

Comment: what source of location, i didnt get you....!

Comment: Please add the HTML code of the webelement.

Comment: <font size="-1" face="ARIAL">
      270 </font>

This is got from inspect element for which i want.

Comment: do you want to store the XPath query itself or the text value of the element that the XPath query points to?

Answer (score 2):

I seeing that this is C#, so not sure if this would work. But you can use a new variable, whose type is WebElement, something like this

```
WebElement ele = webdriver.FindElement(By.Xpath('Xpath_that_you_have'));
```

Please note that you need to replace `Xpath_that_you_have` with the actual xpath that you have mentioned.

then,

use this `ele` element and find the text for the element using the `Text` attribute- using something like this

```
  String s1 = ele.Text;
```

> Update : In C#, text is found using the Text attribute, not the text() method.

Then use the corresponding method to convert the text that you have to `int`, type, which can be converted using the `Convert.Int32(string)` method that you have in C#.

Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690971/selenium-webdriver-c-sharp-get-text) to get a better idea.

-Please change the code in C# accordingly.

Comment: IWebElement ele = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/font"));
            string ele = ele.Text();...............its not working saying that in .text() code ele string is already used and .Text()-Non-invocable number 'IWebElement Text' cannot be used like a method...is anything to do before this?

Comment: Did it solve your issue? Also you can use a better xpath

Comment: No, Its not solved i used xpath...redlines coming under ele and text();                                           

I have a price(270) in my webpage, for that i need store in string(which is text after i do inspect element)  and then in integer for calculation

Comment: Do you know how to find text in C#?

Comment: yes, using findelement(by,xpath("xpath of the text"));

Comment: No. Please see the answer with updated link.

Comment: im unable to do convertion with code that you gave...